# combinatorial way to count representatives of conjugacy class of elements of ord 5

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

I am trying to find a representative of each conjugacy class of order 5 elements in PGL$_6$($\mathbb C$).
Let $r$ in $\mathbb C$ such that $r^5 = 1$  and [ ] denote modular the center of GL$_6(\mathbb C)$.
Thus, we start with $$
[\begin{pmatrix}
r & 0 \\
0 & I_5
\end{pmatrix}]
$$ with r replaced by $r^2, r^3, r^4$ respectively. So we have 4 cases.
Then we have
$$
[\begin{pmatrix}
* & 0 & 0\\
0 & * & 0\\
0 & 0 & I_4
\end{pmatrix}]
$$ where the two * * can be chosen from $r, r^2, r^3, r^4$. We have $10$ = $\binom{4+2-1}2$ in total. Next we have
$$
[\begin{pmatrix}
* & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & * & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & * & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & I_3
\end{pmatrix}]
$$ which gives $18$ = $\binom{4+3-1}3-2$ in total.

My question: for$$
[\begin{pmatrix}
* & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & * & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & * & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & * & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I_2
\end{pmatrix}]
$$ I know the four *'s cannot all be the same, so $\binom{4+4-1}4-4$ . And then the case cannot occur either that three of the four are the same and the one left is different. So we rule out another $_4 P _2$. Then for the rest, what I did was write out them one by one and pick out the repetitions, which is rather tedious. No combination number or pattern applies... I am not quite familiar with combinatorics. Is my question some typical problem in combinatorics?

Edit to be specific: I've used this ordering. First let's write the first four diagonal entries as (****) where the first * being the (1,1) entry. So my ordering goes:

(2211),(3211),(4211),(3311),(4311),(4411), (3221),(4221),(3221),(4221),(4421), (4331),(4431),etc.  I started with (2211) because there should be no four being the same or three of the four being the same.    So far, by calculation, I've already got (4411),(4421),(4331) and (4431) as repetition.  But this is by judging one by one. Do we have a combinatorial way to count without writing out them because I intend to generalize this procedure algorithmically.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you mean by "find all order 5 elements", since there are infinitely many. Do you mean find representatives of conjugacy classes?

Comment: yes, that's right.  Sorry, I will edit.

Comment: But you don't want to find all representatives of each conjugacy class, you want to find one representative from each class.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: yes sir. i've edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well any element of order $5$ is conjugate to a diagonal matrix other that $I_6$ in which the entries are fifth roots of unity.

You can then conjugate by a permutation matrix to have the entries occur in a specified order down the diagonal, like $\omega^0,\omega^1,\ldots, \omega^4$, where $\omega$ is some fixed fifth root of unity.

Of course this is just putting the matrix into Jordan Canonical Form, but since it has finite order all blocks have size $1$.

The above describes the conjugacy classes of order $5$ elements in ${\rm GL}(6,{\mathbb  C})$. To get representatives in ${\rm PGL}(6,{\mathbb  C})$ you just need to keep to work out which representatives are equivalent modulo the scalar matrices, which is straightforward.

Comment: Hello Professor Holt. Thx for the input. I've edited my question. Hopefully this will make myself clearer.

Comment: I misread the question, but going from ${\rm GL}$ to ${\rm PGL}$ is straightforward.

Comment: Yes, it is achievable by working out the equivalence modulo the center one by one. So I suppose there is no combinatorial way to count it at one go (like previously $18$ = $\binom{4+3-1}3-2$) without writing them out? Thank you!

Comment: The classes of ${\rm GL}(6,{\mathbb C})$ correspond to non-decreasing sequences $(a_1,\ldots,a_6)$ with $0 \le a_i \le 4$, and $a_i$ not all zero, and there might be a combinatorial formula for that. In fact there are $210$. In this case multiplying by non-identity scalar does no fix any class so there are $210/5 = 42$ classes in ${\rm PGL}(2,{\mathbb C})$. (But note that in ${\rm GL}(5,{\mathbb C})$, for example, there is a class fixed by multiplying by a scalar.)